# Can I dis-identify myself if I use VPN on sites?

Tags: privacy, anonymity

This is for irc site. but identification mechanism is what I need to know. 
On IRC (since it's the kinpin of tracking,identifying) if I use a different IP, can I still be identified if someone is looking for me. but from a knowledge perspective how do remain anonymous and get fresh on IRC?

> just how do i change my hostname which has no option unlike nickname,realname,identname which i can in the child window?
>   but hostname is the main thing mine.

Comment: Without knowing more about your usage, I don't think that we can answer this. What IRC client are you using? Do you open any links you get from IRC?

Comment: Let's avoid assumptions or blanket statements without sources in questions (re: kingpin of tracking/identifying)

Comment: Also, this question asks a very broad question but then tries to limit it with an example that might not be suitable for the original question. Consider asking either about the general site identification or just regarding IRC.

Comment: my hostname is like Host name: 84ZAAC9.. a number, and i don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 2):

This question is broad, so unfortunately the only answer is that *it depends.*

Regarding any site/protocol: take a look at the traffic. Inspect what exactly you are sending to the server. This will give you an idea of what information can be used to identify you. IRC protocol is pretty straight forward and you should be able to see what parts of the protocol reveal who/where you are.

Comment: your answer is so vague, atleast send a link or please expound on how to take a look at the traffic. i am not a security expert.

Comment: You can use Wireshark

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay anonymous into an IRC server you need to masquerade your real IP. You can achieve this by using a VPN. In fact if an user of the IRC server will perform a whois command on you, he will see the VPN IP and not your real one.

Comment: i get /whois Nick: kasduiaisd Real name: purple Ident name: ~a. on pidgin. but on kiwiirc i get a number instead of a (by computer/hostname) maybe because of webclient nature, so if i change ident name,nick obviously,and purple i can disidentify myself from a irc person looking for me? she said she identifies me with subnet mask, i said 255.255.. it's same for all. she said"no that's the number of total subnets and she identified me by subnets"? i'm confused and trepidated

Comment: also is http://www.slyck.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45954 has extra info, should i use ports,etc. i'm a bit hesitant about their method vs yours

Comment: There is more to anonymity than just hiding your IP. For example, a web IRC client may use cookies and JavaScript.

Comment: cricco95 Neil Smithline i can't change userid, also known as hostname, remaining verything i can, but there is no option available to change it unlike nick,realname,identname, etc. i just want to know that my question is not broad.